# Manual postgres migration for Django (python) app

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgresql-9.3, update, alter-table

I have a Django (python) data model called `Message`:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sending_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I added `sender = models.ForeignKey(User)` to this model in Django's **models.py** code. Next, I wanted to explore doing schema changes to reflect this change in the code without invoking `syncdb` or `south`. I.e. manually updating the schema of my postgresql backend.

So I logged into `psql` and did the following:

```
ALTER TABLE message ADD COLUMN "sender" INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
ALTER TABLE message ADD CONSTRAINT fk_message_user FOREIGN KEY (sender) REFERENCES user(id);
```

With those two commands, I successfully added a new column with default value 1, containing a foreign key to Django's built-in `User` model.

After I had done that, I figured I had successfully approximated what Django does with `syncdb` or `migrate`. I ran my web app - everything looked good. But then as soon as I hit the first database transaction in my code, the following error resulted:

> DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until
>   end of transaction block

I'm unable to get it to work unless I delete the column I manually added (or rollback the transaction), but not otherwise. `syncdb` is an option, but let's exclude it for this question.

What did I miss when I manually provisioned that foreignkey field? Can someone walk me through the process? I'm assuming running the Django `migration` command simply automates steps one could have done manually too. Since I need to understand the anatomy of that process, I'm doing it by hand. How would you add a foreign key field manually to a pg database in the sort of scenario I've pointed out?

Comment: What's the output of django-admin sqlmigrate or  django-admin inspectdb ?

Comment: Good question. Now that I try `django-admin inspectdb`, I get a configuration error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: Hmm, I was wrong about the inspectdb, it's been a few years. What does the sqlmigrate output? is it anywhere similar to the DDL you are running?

Comment: Getting the same config error there too. Will need to figure out how to run one of these commands - you're right, they might give a better clue.

Comment: Instead try `python manage.py inspectdb`